# Pandas index: Converting localized object to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe like the following:

```
                        A   
2014-06-02 09:00:00-04:00   ...
2014-06-02 10:00:00-04:00   ...
2014-06-02 11:00:00-04:00   ...
2014-06-02 12:00:00-04:00   ...
```

I need the index to be a datetime to make some operations so I am trying:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

Please note that the index is localized (-04:00)

pandas 0.24.2

Comment: as the error says, why don't you pass `utc`: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may follow the suggestion from the error:

`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)`

You may also convert the time to a `-04:00` timezone with `tz_convert('US/Eastern')`